# Issue with delete statement in merge statement

Tags: sql-server, merge

I am working with `merge into` statement

I have a table that looks like this (first I insert like this) using below query:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |

**table type :**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[userid] AS TABLE(
    [userid] [bigint] NULL
)
GO
```

Now I want the below output :

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |

I write the below query like this:

```
--use test
declare @sid varchar(100) = '5'
declare @uid as userid

insert into @uid(userid) values(2)
insert into @uid(userid) values(3)
--insert into @uid(userid) values(5)    // I remove this line 
insert into @uid(userid) values(6)

MERGE INTO dbo.test_master AS dest
USING @uid AS sou ON
    dest.sid = @sid
    AND
    sou.userid = dest.testid
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    dest.testid = sou.userid
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT( sid, testid )
    VALUES( @sid, sou.userid )
--WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
--    THEN
--        DELETE
;
```

I am trying to achieve this output

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |

I am using `delete` keyword, see my SQL query, but it is deleting the all records from the table. I try, but can't work it out.

Comment: you need to rename your `TYPE dbo.userid` to `TYPE dbo.UserIdTable` otherwise you'll just confuse yourself (and us...)

Comment: And column names on your sample data would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to pre-filter the destination table**, otherwise *all* rows, even ones that have a different `sid` will be deleted. You can pre-filter with a CTE or a view.

> I note that the `WHEN MATCHED` clause makes no sense, as the only column being updated is the join column, which obviously matches anyway.

```sql
declare @sid varchar(100) = '5';
declare @uid as userid;

insert into @uid (userid) values
  (2),
  (3),
--  (5),    -- I remove this line 
  (6);

WITH dest AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.test_master dest
    WHERE dest.sid = @sid
)
MERGE INTO dest
USING @uid AS sou ON
    sou.userid = dest.testid
-- WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
--    dest.testid = sou.userid   -- doesn't make sense
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT( sid, testid )
    VALUES( @sid, sou.userid )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=05200d217ff924ec01ffa207a14d4bf7)